# HTML filter on Template Toolkit. perl

Tags: html, perl, web, catalyst, template-toolkit

Can someone tell me why in others code I saw expression like: `[% variable | html | html %]`. What is the reason to use two html filters? For example in perl catalyst controller:

```
sub index :Path Args(0) {
    my($self, $c) = @_;

    $c->stash->{template} = 'index.tt';
    $c->stash->{variable} = 'hello';
}

Index.tt:
<p> [% variable | html | html %] world</p>
```

Comment: Hard to know the answer without seeing one of the examples.

Comment: Hello sir. I meant that in our company the construction [% variable | html | html %] instead of [% variable | html%], for what purpose can it be used and is it possible at all? Template Toolkit, perl-Catalyst. @DaveCross

Comment: In book and documentation it uses as  [% FILTER html %] some text [% END %] @DaveCross

Comment: There's no practical reason to use the HTML filter once, let along twice, with the hard coded data in the code. While I can think of some reasons why double encoding might appear in some code, it would be highly speculative and not suitable for a SO answer. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and note that it says: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced."